# Recursion Tree Algorithm Math Quesiton

Tags: induction, recursion

[image: Screen shot from text book]

Hello, I am rusty on my math. Can someone expand step by step whats going on in the induction hypothesis. Where does the 1 go? How is it being added? I just am not seeing the algebra steps that should be obvious to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Although it may be useful to provide an image from your textbook, this should be accompanied by stating the problem you want help with in your own words.  In addition you should take the opportunity to explain your own approach in more detail, e.g. what leads you to ask "Where does the 1 go?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$T(n)>2^{(n-1)/2}+2^{(n-2)/2}+1>2^{(n-2)/2}+2^{(n-2)/2}$$
because $$1>0, (n-1)/2>(n-2)/2$$
 so by transitivity, $$T(n)>2^{(n-2)/2}+2^{(n-2)/2}=2^{n/2}$$

Comment: Can you expand on this... I am googling but transitivity I learned its related to set theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation Thank you.

Comment: It's simply a property of the greater than function. If a>b>c then a>c by the transitive property